# python smtplib sending mail without recipient

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I'm using python smtplib to send emails. They arrive to the destination, but the "To" field is missing.
In Gmail the "To" field is empty, but in thunderbird says "undisclosed-recipients". I have made some google search, but I didn't find anything.

I don't see any error on the code that explains this, but I was following some code snippets from another question of Stack Overflow, so may be I'm missing something.

This is the code for the mail sender:

```
def connect_and_send(send_from, send_to, carbon_copy, msg):
    confp = ConfigParser()
    confp.read("config/mail.ini")
    server  = str(confp.get('mail', 'host'))
    port    = str(confp.get('mail', 'port'))
    user    = str(confp.get('mail', 'username'))
    password= str(confp.get('mail', 'password'))
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP_SSL()
    smtp.connect(server, port)
    smtp.login(
        user,
        password
    )
    send_to.append(carbon_copy)
    smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())


def send_mail(send_from, send_to, carbon_copy, subject, text, signature, files=None):
    assert isinstance(send_to, list)
    if ARGS.debug:
        print "MAIL to:", send_to
        print "MAIL from:", send_from
        print "MAIL subject", subject
        print "with {0} files attached".format(len(files))
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg["Subject"] = subject
    msg["From"] = send_from
    msg["Date"] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg["To"] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)

    msg.attach(MIMEText(text+"\n"+signature))
    for f in files or []:
        part = MIMEBase('image', "png")
        part.set_payload(f[1].read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="{0}.png"'.format(f[0]))
        msg.attach(part)

    if ARGS.debug and not ARGS.force_send:
        print msg.as_string()
    else:
        connect_and_send(send_from, send_to, carbon_copy, msg.as_string())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv) (full disclose: I'm the developer).

The full code would be:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP(send_from, host = host, port = port)
if files is None:
    files = []
yag.send(send_to, subject, contents =  [text, signature] + files, bcc = carbon_copy)
```

Note that files will be smartly attached already! (given they are local path to filenames)

I would also suggest to use the keyring of yagmail to prevent from having to store the password locally.

You can get yagmail from pip:

```
pip install yagmail   # python 2
pip3 install yagmail  # python 3
```

Also, since it looks like you're making use of some quite specific mail needs, I'm sure you can benefit from yagmail and it should pay off to read the [github documentation](https://github.com/kootenpv). Feel free to raise issues/requests.

Comment: thank you, however this doesn't solve my problem. Seems like something with my application because if I use the function from the command line interpreter works.